# I am trying to set a new value to the singleton method that has already being defined in ruby but I could not find a proper method to do so

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
define_singleton_method(:node_name){ "NODE0003" }
=> :node_name

node_name
=> "NODE0003"
```

I tried to change this value using `set_to` method but gives the error

```
node_name.set_to("Node")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /Users/kr018/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /Users/kr018/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /Users/kr018/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):54
        1: from (irb):55:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `set_to' for "NODE0003":String)
```

Could someone help on this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the value"? (Change the value *of what*?) Also, what is `set_to`? This is not a core ruby method, and you haven't provided a definition,

Comment: do you wan to add a new method or redefine an exiting method in an existing class? For it do monkey patching.